I want to write and deploy a single thread, single process Flask/Gunicorn application? How can I maintain persistent state?
Please note that if you have seen a similar question from myself on stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions this question is intended to be focused with (hopefully) a specific answer, rather than a more open ended discussion with a range of possible answers.
I am writing a Flask application which I intend to run with Gunicorn. This application needs to maintain some internal state. For the sake of argument, assume this internal state is as simple as a key-value store. It could be as simple as a Python dictionary, with the webapp presenting GET and POST methods to get or update key value pairs.
In order to share this state, I must configure Gunicorn to run as a single process. (Otherwise some mechanism would be required to share state between processes, and this isn't something I want to implement.)
I could configure it to run with multiple threads. But I would have to protect the data structure using locks. (Again, this isn't a route I want to go down. This is a very simple demonstration project, and the web app part is not the important part of the demo.)
From this I conclude that the best way to deploy this is with Gunicorn configured to use a single process and a single thread. This solves any data-sharing and concurrencuy issues.
What I do not understand is how do I create shared state in a Flask application?
I have read multiple sources which appear to have conflicting information. Some sources say this is not possible. Others say that the flask.g object can be used, but only within a single request. (Which I assume means the state will be created and destroyed many times throughout the lifetime of the application? If this is the case this clearly will not work.)
Here is some example code. How should I be using the state of global_data in the context of the GET and POST requests?
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

global_data = {} # ? how should I initialize this global state ?

@app.get('/get')
def get():
    context = request.json
    key = content.get('key')
    return global_data[key]

@app.post('/put')
def put():
    context = request.json
    key = content.get('key')
    value = content.get('value')
    global_data[key] = value


Partial answer:

In relation to the maintaining of persistent state, it is actually trivial.
All the documentation suggests that maintaining state is a difficult thing. You will likely read that Flask is designed to be used as a stateless application, implying that it cannot maintain state.
However, this is not quite accurate. Maintaining state is as simple as creating variables within your Python code which contains the Flask webserver code (ideally somewhere near the top)

Things to be aware of:

This will only work if multiple processes are disabled. The application has to run in single process mode.
If you run with multiple threads, then you will need to use mutexes (aka locks) to protect the data which is shared between threads. (In this case, the shared data will be a global variable.)

There might be a better design, which maintains a similar level of relativel simplicity to this.
There certainly are much better designs which ensure that the Flask part of the application does not contain the main state-holding logic/data structures.
Ideally, one would probably split this into two processes which communicate either via a socket connection, a message broker (Kafka or RabbitMQ etc) or some other data storage system (perhaps Redis or a database).
I didn't want to go to this level of effort in this case.
